# Android FaceDetector without user interaction?

Tags: android, face-detection

I'd like to ask a question about the Android FaceDetector.Face class. I spent a reasonable time searching around and reading documents, but still don't see the big picture. I'd like to understand whether it is feasible to do the following:

An app that performs face detection without user interaction. For example, I want to monitor a toddler playing with my Kindle Fire in another room. Of course I can't ask the kid to take a picture of himself every 5 seconds so as to start the face detection, so the app should do these things:

1)wake up every 5 seconds;
2)take a picture;
3)detect the face;
4)send me an alert if the face is not detected.

Here are my questions:
A)is it possible to write my app with the Android FaceDetector.Face class?
B)if possible, what's the rough steps?
C)if not possible, what is the alternative?

Thanks in advance for your answers/ideas. If links to documents, tutorials, and/or code samples could be provided, that would be even more helpful.

[Edit: I modified my question per Geobits' answer and comment.]

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, because the camera needs a preview View to function, even if it's a dummy one that doesn't actually show the preview. Anything that counts for that would probably interrupt the foreground app. Side note: while your stated use case isn't, the idea it would be possible is downright creepy.

Comment: @Geobits: Indeed the original use scenario, if possible, could be easily abused. I've changed my approach a little bit, so the face detection is done with the user being aware of it. Is it feasible now?